# Java: Changing the speed of a rectangle along a path with a slider

Tags: java, javafx, slider, javafx-8

In this program I am working on, I am trying to get it where the slider controls how fast the square goes along the path of lines. The slider works but the problem is that the slider only changes the speed when the square is done tracing the path. I am trying to make it so that the slider changes the speed while the square is in motion. My code is listed below and I am needing help please. Thank you

```
package endofyearproject;

import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Endofyearproject extends Application {
// public static void main(String[] args)
//{
//
// launch(args);
//
//}
   private boolean doAnother;
   private ColorPicker picker;
   private Rectangle rect;
   private Slider speed;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       setSpeed(new Slider(0,96,12));
       speed.setTranslateX(50);
       speed.setTranslateY(450);
       speed.setPrefSize(360,20);
      // speed.setShowTickLabels(true);
       picker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);
       picker.setOnAction(this::processpick);

       Text mytext = new Text(35, 100, "");
       rect = new Rectangle(30, 100, 30, 30);
       Group rectText = new Group(rect, mytext);

       Line myline1 = new Line(30, 360, 50, 50);
       Line myline2 = new Line(50, 50, 70, 80);
       Line myline3 = new Line(70, 80, 100, 150);
       Line myline4 = new Line(100, 150, 130, 20);
       Line myline5 = new Line(130, 20, 150, 360);
       Line myline6 = new Line(150, 360, 180, 280);
       Line myline7 = new Line(180, 280, 200, 330);
       Line myline8 = new Line(200, 330, 250, 70);
       Line myline9 = new Line(250, 70, 320, 360);
       Line myline10 = new Line(320, 360, 360, 360);
       Line myline11 = new Line(360, 360, 380, 390);
       Line myline12 = new Line(380, 390, 430, 25);
       Line myline13 = new Line(430, 25, 460, 370);

       Path path = new Path();
       path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(30, 360));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(50, 50));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(70, 80));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(100, 150));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(130, 20));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(150, 360));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(180, 280));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(200, 330));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(250, 70));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(320, 360));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(360, 360));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(380, 390));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(430, 25));
       path.getElements().add(new LineTo(460, 370));

       PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();

       pathTransition.setNode(rectText);
       pathTransition.setPath(path);

       pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
       getSpeed().setValue(pathTransition.getCurrentRate());
       Button play = new Button("Play");
       play.setTranslateX(110);
       play.setTranslateY(400);

       play.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               pathTransition.stop();

               pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(getSpeed().getValue()));
               pathTransition.setCycleCount(1);
               pathTransition.play();
           }
       });
       Button pause = new Button("Pause");
       pause.setTranslateX(200);
       pause.setTranslateY(400);
       pause.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
               pathTransition.pause();
           }
       });
       Button resume = new Button("Resume");
       resume.setTranslateX(300);
       resume.setTranslateY(400);
       resume.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

           public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

               if (pathTransition.getStatus() == PathTransition.Status.PAUSED) {
                   pathTransition.play();
               }

           }
       });

       Group root = new Group(picker, rectText, myline1, myline2, myline3, myline4, myline5, myline6, myline7, myline8,
               myline9, myline10, myline11, myline12, myline13, getSpeed(), play, pause, resume);
       Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
       stage.setTitle("Ride at Amusement Park");
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();

   }

   public void processpick(ActionEvent event) {
       rect.setFill(picker.getValue());
   }

   /**
   * @return the speed
   */
   public Slider getSpeed() {
       return speed;
   }


   public void setSpeed(Slider aSpeed) {
       speed = aSpeed;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the `rate` property of the animation to the `Slider`'s value:

```
setSpeed(new Slider(0, 96, 1));

...

pathTransition.rateProperty().bind(speed.valueProperty());
```

Note that this way you must not use a setter to assign the `rate` property.

(Your current code only updates the value on a button press.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try with the below code. Just place it after initializing PathTransition. I hope the inline comments are explanatory.

```
speed.valueProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
    if (pathTransition.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
        // Get the current point in the duration
        double point = pathTransition.getCurrentTime().toMillis() / pathTransition.getDuration().toMillis();
        // Stop the animation
        pathTransition.stop();
        // Set new duration
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(speed.getValue()));
        // Compute the time to the current point.
        double jumpTo = Duration.seconds(speed.getValue()).toMillis() * point;
        // Jump to the current point
        pathTransition.jumpTo(Duration.millis(jumpTo));
        // And start the animation again
        pathTransition.play();
    }
});
```

Also, not related to the actual question, try working with JavaFX provided layouts. Things will be much simpler than wrapping all nodes in a Group and positioning them.